# database transactions when 'consistent state' / 'atomicity is not needed

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm tryin to understand when to use database transactions if I don't have the need for consistent state or "strict" atomicity.

I don't have some banking style requirement that needs a reduction in one column to offset an addition somewhere else.

I do have some form of atomicity, but only for 'ease of use' and I'm wondering if that's enough to use a db transaction.

Specifically, I require my user to create an entry in table A, B and C. Table C depends on B and B depends on A. On the browser I actually display all that data in one form and when the user submits, it is sent to the backend where an entry in table A is attempted, followed by B (with the reference Id just created from A), followed by C (with the reference id created from B).

If A fails, the User is reshown the form with the error message regarding A.
If A succeeds, but B fails, then the user is redirected to a page to add B & C. 
If A & B succeed and C fails the user is redirected to a page to add C.

As you can see this can be quite a lot of error handling and a transaction that just says "All succeeded" or "something failed, nothing created", would be the easiest since I could just keep the user on the same page or redirect if successful. Also keep in mind the likelihood of failure on B & C is quite low since I do validation on client side...

My question is when should I be using the transaction approach vs the error handling approach when my need for atomicity is not so "strict". What are some considerations I need to make before choosing a transaction approach or a series of inserts approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a transaction in cases where it's "all or nothing". IOW, if B or C fails, then the save (insert or update) to A should be rolled back. If all do not pass, then none do, and the database remains as it was before the attempt. That said, it can be difficult to do a transaction in some languages. In your case, I might prefer to create a stored procedure, pass all the data to that procedure. Inside the procedure, I would wrap the actions in a transaction, and have the procedure return a pass/fail indicator, or the record ID from table A that was created, or a -1 if any part failed.